# NetBeans default Jlist changing it into an arraylist

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, arraylist, jlist

Basically, I have the default creator from the GUI Builder in NetBeans producing this code:

```
IPAddressList = new javax.swing.JList();

IPAddressList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
    String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
    public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
    public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
});

AddressList.setViewportView(IPAddressList);
```

What I want to change this to is to have an ArrayList instead of a vector where I can use the add and remove functions of that ArrayList via buttons.  I'm new to the GUI world and I've been trying a few different ways (I've no idea where to put DefaultListModel to make it work correctly).  Please be as specific as you can in answering this.

All I really need is a Jlist code that I can change this code into that will have an ArrayList that if I say IPAddressList.arraylist.add() it will add something to the ArrayList inside this Jlist and update the Jlist accordingly.  Same thing with removing.  Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

*Approach 1 (mutable):*

```
List<String> myList = 
      new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Item 1", 
                                    "Item 2", 
                                    "Item 3", 
                                    "Item 4", 
                                    "Item 5"));

DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList myJList = new JList(model);
```

Updating:

```
model.clear();
for (String item : myList) {
   model.addElement(item);
}
```

*Approach 2 (immutable):*

```
List<String> myList = ...    
JList myJList = new JList(myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]));
```

Admittedly, the second approach does not use `DefaultListModel` but here's why it's included:

Using DefaultListModel's [addElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addElement%28java.lang.Object%29) is relatively slow for models holding around 200 or more items. Passing in an array of `Object` to [JList(E[] listData)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#JList%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) is faster than adding the elements individually using a `DefaultListModel` as a new `AbstractListModel` is created based on the `List` elements. This is discussed and alternatives presented in this [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=20aad6f1c0ca847e78f661c8e7969?bug_id=4121430).

Comment: +1 but most of OPs here never used Java7 & Swing a Generics, please to notify about ... :-)

Comment: Ok, fair point, I have reverted to Java 6 to match OP's question :)